# Unable to add hyperlink to repeating table

Tags: php

I have table named `ipcam (camera id,camera name,camera model,IP address, Url, Port)`.
I am successfully able to retrieve data from MySQL db.
Now what i intend to do is add an extra field to table at the end called `Delete` - which is hyperlink and deletes the row by sending id to `deletecam.php` page here is the code:

```
<?php                               
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * from ipcam WHERE user_id = {$user_id}");
echo"<table border=5 colspan=6> <tr><th>IP CAMERA ID &nbsp;&nbsp;</th><th>IP CAMERA NAME &nbsp;&nbsp;</th><th>CAMERA MODEL&nbsp;&nbsp;</th> <th>IP ADDRESS&nbsp;&nbsp;</th> <th>URL&nbsp;&nbsp;</th> <th>PORT&nbsp;&nbsp;</th><th>DELETE&nbsp;&nbsp;</th></tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr>
    <td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $row['model'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $row['ipaddress'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $row['url'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $row['port'] . "</td>      
    <td> echo"<html><h3>"; <a href="/deletecam.php?id= <?php echo urlencode($row['id']); ?> "> Delete </a>  echo"</h3></html>"; </td></tr>"; 

}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

However I am having strange problem when I run this code the error is:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '>' in C:\xampp\htdocs\IPCAM\cameralist.php on line 176
```

the error comes for delete when i try to include the hyperlink in the code.
Am i doing something wrong with syntax or its not possible to do such thing.

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*` functions. Also, you have unterminated string constants. Learn how to form strings properly.

Comment: sorry but can u pls help me to add this hyperlink

<a href="/deletecam.php?id= <?php echo urlencode(" . $row['id'] . ") ; ?> "> Delete </a>

 my table inbetween one <td></td> fields at the end

Comment: Just as the error says, go to line 176 and correct your code.

Comment: i think there is some confusion using anchor tag along with php tag
thats where i am getting error what could be proper syntax in your point of view
<a href="page?id=<?php echo urlencode($row['id']); ?> ">Delete</a> ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>
    <td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $row['model'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $row['ipaddress'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $row['url'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $row['port'] . "</td>      
    <td> <h3> <a href='/deletecam.php?id=" . urlencode($row['id']) . "'> Delete </a> </h3> </td></tr>"; 
}
```

You shouldn't have `<html>` inside the table. And you can't use `<?php` inside echoed strings.

Comment: Thanks a lot Barmar you exactly figured out and solve my exact problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, you should not get a error. You were not ending the echo string.

```
 <?php 

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * from ipcam WHERE user_id = {$user_id}");


    echo"<table border=5 colspan=6> <tr><th>IP CAMERA ID &nbsp;&nbsp;</th><th>IP CAMERA NAME &nbsp;&nbsp;</th><th>CAMERA MODEL&nbsp;&nbsp;</th> <th>IP ADDRESS&nbsp;&nbsp;</th> <th>URL&nbsp;&nbsp;</th> <th>PORT&nbsp;&nbsp;</th><th>DELETE&nbsp;&nbsp;</th></tr>";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {

    echo "<tr>
    <td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $row['model'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $row['ipaddress'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $row['url'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $row['port'] . "</td>"  ; // i missed a " here
    ?>
    <td> <h3><a href="/deletecam.php?id= <?php echo urlencode($row['id']); ?> "> Delete </a>  </h3></td></tr> 

    <?php
            }

    echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: Want to explain to him why his unterminated string constant was throwing errors?

Comment: The error is still there...

Comment: I tried this its still giving me a error like this:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in C:\xampp\htdocs\IPCAM\cameralist.php on line 176

Comment: But how could i know which one of your line is 176. Can you be more descriptive?

Comment: i think there is some confusion using anchor tag along with php tag thats where i am getting error what could be proper syntax in your point of view <a href="page?id=<?php echo urlencode($row['id']); ?> ">Delete</a> ?

Comment: you anchor tag is ok, but the problem is with your php code. You are not ending the second echo statement and already starting the third echo statement. First end the echo statements appropriately. Then, what is the point in using the <html> tag in the echo statement. You are already using table and its tags which are already part of html .